# is co-NP-hard contained in EXPTIME-hard or vice-versa?

Tags: complexity-theory, co-np

is **co-NP-hard** contained in **EXPTIME-hard** or vice-versa?

Comment: What is EXPTIME-hard?  It's always good to include the definition of possibly obscure terms  so that your question is self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

It is known that co-NP $\subseteq$ PSPACE $\subseteq$ EXPTIME, so every EXPTIME-hard problem, must also be a co-NP-hard problem (as there is a polynomial time reduction from every $L\in$ EXPTIME to it, and therefore also from every $L\in$ co-NP)

Therefore EXPTIME-hard $\subseteq$ co-NP-hard.

Note that this argument **does not hold** for co-NP-complete and EXPTIME-complete. This is still an open problem (i believe).